# The process cannot access the file XXX because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

When I run my application, I get this error on the first "using" here:

```
    public void CreateFile(string filePath)
    {

        //Create File
        string fileLoc = filePath;

        FileStream fs = null;
        if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
        {
            using (fs = File.Create(fileLoc))
            {

            }
        }

    }

    public void WriteFile(string filePath)
    {
        //Write to File
        string fileLoc = filePath;

        if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
            {
                sw.Write("Some sample text for the file");
            }
        }
    }
```

A file from that directory was previously opened and read from, but the StreamReader was closed after it was read. I'm not sure if that has any significance with this error. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that code.  Is it possible your application was already running or that the file is opened in another application?

Comment: Does the problem repro if you turn off all virus checkers? This symptom is often associated with overly aggressive virus checkers.

Answer (score 0):

Your check of `File.Exists` before the line where you get the error suggests something strange is going on, such as trying to use a directory path as `filePath`, or multithreaded race conditions.

Comment: _'when other processes are using them'_  ... _in a certain way_. That is, files are perfectly readily shareable when the handle is created accordingly.

Comment: @GrantThomas true, clarified my answer to: ...when other processes have  a lock on them.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. But I don't need to worry about looking into creating the file or writing to it any differently, correct?

Comment: @user2340818 I thought so, but on second look, since you're only trying to create the file if you find that it doesn't exist, you can't just be trying to call `File.Create` on a file that's already created and opened in a file; you shouldn't be getting the error you are. Are you running in a multi-threaded environment? Maybe you need to add an appropriate `lock` statement so that only one thread tries to access a file at once.

What is your fileLoc string? Maybe it's something invalid, a directory, or something else weird and is causing this error.

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. The "filePath" I was using linked to a folder that was open, as opposed to creating a file IN that folder (what I wanted to do). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2340818 cool! I've modified my answer so that it might help others, and might make sense for you to accept as the correct/best answer.